# Can not create app using create-react-app on my pc

Tags: reactjs

**When I try to create an app using create-react-app that give an error**

You are running `create-react-app` 5.0.0, which is behind the latest release (5.0.1).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:

- npm uninstall -g create-react-app

I am trying this command: npm uninstall -g create-react-app
but no solution

Answer (score 1):

You have to run `npx create-react-app myApp` rather than running it directly.

Comment: It is not working

Comment: Do you have `npm` installed?

Answer (score 0):

npx create-react-app my-app

As per their documentation